# How to highlight the projects I was involved during my postdoc in CV?

Tags: cv

I had worked in several projects during my postdocs in past years. I would like to highlight them in my CV. My question is what could be the proper heading to highlight those projects. e.g. **projects involved during postdoc**

Comment: Did the projects lead to publications?

Comment: I've seen people use subheadings under each research position they have, where they briefly describe the projects they worked on, principal contributions. Usually just at the level of bullets.

Comment: These projects were basically Govt sponsored projects with many research themes. My adviser was the PI of one theme. Yes, we had published few results in peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: If it's published then it should be included in the section about publication which is enough. Other than that I'm using a separate "research overview" file, where I describe all the different  topics I've worked in on a few pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a section entitled "Research Highlights". Then, point-wise, a single sentence describing the main research result of each highlight. Maximum impact would be firsts and records set, e.g. "First to measure the effect of X upon Y"; "Discovery of correlation between W and Z"; "Tightest limits set on parameter R", etc.